# the number of solutions to polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring, geometric-series, discriminant

The problem is that, for the function $f$: 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=c_{0} + c_{1}x + c_{2}x^{2} + \ldots + c_{n}x^{n}, c_i \in \mathbb Z
\end{equation*}
then for $f(x)=0$, how many distinct solutions for $x$ **at most** ?

What I have known:

1. there are $1$ solution at most when $n=1$.
2. and $2$ at most for $n=2$, since I know $f(x)$ can be rewritten as $(x-a)(x-b)$.

But about the subsequent parts, $n=3,4,5,...$

Is there any guru could offer advices ? THANKS !

Comment: That’s not a geometric series.

Comment: Without some constraints on the coefficients, all you can really conclude is that $f$ will have at most $n$ distinct roots.

Comment: The answer is $n$. A polynomial of order $n$ has $n$ roots, at most $n$ distinct.

Comment: Check out the [FTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra). And don't call it a geometric series since it's neither geometric nor a series.

Comment: It is at most $n,$ by induction on $n.$ If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with $f(r)=0,$ you can write $f(x)=(x-r)g(x)$ for some polynomial $g$ of degree one lower. Then you have to show that if $f(a)=0,$ then either $a=r$ or $g(a)=0.$